# Passing parameters to a Dataset from an expression in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, dataset

In a report I would like to have the individual static text fields internationalised.
The idea is to have a default word or phrase like "Date and Time" and pass this string to a dataset with static parameters such as Culture_Code.

My question is how do I set the value of the parameter to pass to the dataset BEFORE calling the dataset within each individual expression of each text box?

Example expression;

```
Parameter!Text_To_Translate.Value = "Date and Time"
=First(Fields!Translated_Text.Value, "Language_Text")
```

I am using SSRS 2008R2.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to pass the parameter before calling the dataset then you have to pass the parameter in the url of reportserver

```
http://localhost/reportserver
```

---

url format:

```
http://<localhost/servername>/reportserver/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?<report_name>&rs:Command=Render&parameter_name=value
```

---

here the way you have to pass the value.

Answer (score 0):

If your report layout is such that all of the text fields to be internationalized are in one or two regions, it may be better to set those regions up as data regions and use a separate query (or queries) to populate them, based on your Culture_Code parameter value.

This assumes you are pulling the localized values out of a data source you can connect to - which may be updated or extended over time.